# Hat position is fixed on page, doesn't move down when you Run a code snippet

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash-2020

When a code snippet is executed it expands to show output, and everything below it moves down -- except for **hats** on profile pics:

| *Initial view* | *When running* |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Initial view] | [image: When running] |

On closer inspection, there appear to be two hats: one that stays fixed, and another one that does move down.

Page where screenshots were made:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65320526/1220550

Comment: MSE Bug report: [If you run a code snippet, a hat still appears (hats are above snippets in the Z-order)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357942)

Comment: Seems fixed for me, just takes a second for the one in the output to disappear.

Comment: That hat jumps back in to position when hovered, but then remains too far down the screen when the StackSnippet is closed.

Comment: not fixed, I can reproduce it right now on SO. Firefox 84.0, Windows 10

Comment: Disregard my last comment, I forgot to "force-reload" the page (Ctrl+F5) before testing, now it's fixed :).